# How to display all the tables created in sqlite database on python3

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
    
conn = sqlite3.connect('boo2.db')
c = conn.cursor()
    
x = c.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table'")
    
for y in x:
    print(x)
```

the output is

```
********************************
<sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x00272DE0>
Process finished with exit code 0
**************************************
```

But not any tables ... How to get the table names ?

Comment: You are printing `x` not `y`. change it to `print(y)`

Comment: My Bad ...Thanks a lot Ian for pointing out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to fetch the results from the query:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('boo2.db')
c = conn.cursor()

x=c.execute("SELECT * FROM sqlite_master where type='table'")

for y in x.fetchall():
    print(y)
```